# shortest vector problem with lattice using Euclidean $L^2$ norm

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, integer-lattices, np-complete

I'm wondering about the time complexity for the closest vector problem and the shortest vector problem with a twist:

This is the statement for the SVP I wish to consider:

$$\lambda(H) = \min_{v \in H- {\mathbf\lbrace{1}\rbrace}} ||v||_{L^2}$$

$H = w_1^{\mathbb Z} \odot w_2^{\mathbb Z},$ where $w_1=(a,1)$ and $w_2=(1,b)$ for some $a,b>0; a,b\neq 1,$ and $(x_1,y_1)\odot(x_2,y_2)=(x_1 x_2, y_1 y_2)$ and $w^{\mathbb Z} = \{ w^n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \}.$ And $L^2$ is the Euclidean norm.

The vector, crucially has to be *non-zero* or it's trivial. Here is some info on the [closest vector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem#Closest_vector_problem_(CVP)).

I think this can be described as measuring a multiplicative lattice using the norm from the additive lattice.

> How does this compare? Is this problem any harder or easier than the standard shortest/closest vector problems?